# Binding static string in static class to textbox

Tags: wpf, data-binding, static, textblock

I want to make a static string to show feedback message.

Configuration.cs

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public static class Configuration
    {
        public static string Message { get; set; }
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="69,92,0,0"
        TextWrapping="Wrap" 
        Text="{Binding Source={x:Static s:Configuration.Message}}"    
        VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="119" Width="366"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Calc calculation = new Calc();

            int calc = calculation.add(1, 3);
        }
    }
}
```

Calc.cs

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    class Calc
    {
        public int add(int a, int b)
        {
            int c = 0;

            try
            {
                c = a + b;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Configuration.Message = ex.Message; // I want to show this message.
            }

            return c;
        }
    }
}
```

So if the program has error on Calc.cs, it changes the value in Configuration.Message.

I want to use data binding for that. Can you give me any advice or sample code?

Thanks.

Comment: Static classes cannot implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface if that's what you're asking

Answer (score 0):

Create your own event in the static class for handling the property changed as INPC doesn't work